# How harmful is aluminium?

Tags: neuroscience, medicine, toxicology, vaccination, diet

I have been taught in school that aluminium is harmful for brain.
Thus sour meals should not be cooked in aluminium pots and it is unhealthy to add lemon juice to tea while there is teabag in the cup, as acid facilitates aluminium release.

The only safe limit for aluminium intake I know is FDA pediatric limit for parenteral sources (5 μg/kg bw/day). I know no research the limit is based on, but I have read [an abstract of a paper claiming it was impossible to comply with the regulation in patients weighting less than 50 kg](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0148607108316187).

Nowadays aluminium ions are present in several vaccines, which are considered safe to be injected intramuscularly in infants despite despite being  nowhere near the FDA limit.

I'm quite confused how strict should I be in avoidance of aluminium intake (especially dietetary intake - which I expect to be far less effective than parenteral).

[EDIT]

It seems aluminium is also a component of some [antacids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antacid#Algeldrate) which are used to treat heartburn.
Does it mean aluminium consumption is safe at general, or it is just considered to be less harmful than acid indigestion (there are [some side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antacid#Side_effects)  mentioned - but nothing about accumulation in the brain)?

Comment: @RonJohn I think iron is even more hamful then. ;)

Comment: Too true, but this wasn't a comparative question...  :)

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the discount was worthwhile on that depleted uranium skillet.

Comment: @jamesqf if God had wanted man to hit with aluminum bats, he wouldn't have invented trees!

Comment: well the thing to understand is that "toxicity"  is relative.Anything can be harmful if consumed in high quantities .

Comment: If cooked using aluminum pots ,the aluminium reacts with the aluminium creating aluminium salts ,which may be more harmful than the metal in elemental state, as it accumulates easily.

Comment: a bit of both and also, sorry for the typo .-. , been doing that all day

Comment: @pranavB23 it nicely fits the level of abstraction of other comments ;)

Comment: @pranavB23: Yes, for instance both water and oxygen are necessary for life, but too much of either will kill you.  E.g. https://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/features/water-intoxication#1

Comment: @jamesqf which reminds me about threat of [dihydrogen monoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrogen_monoxide_hoax#History) ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/phs/phs.asp?id=1076&tid=34) is a link to the Public Health Statement for Aluminum produced by the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) in the United States.  There is much more information on the web page but the following are some of the more pertinent points to your question.

**Potential Health Effects**

**Workers**

> Workers who breathe large amounts of aluminum dusts can
>   have lung problems, such as coughing or changes that show up in chest
>   X-rays. The use of breathing masks and controls on the levels of dust
>   in factories have largely eliminated this problem.
>
> Some workers who breathe aluminum-containing dusts or aluminum fumes
>   have decreased performance in some tests that measure functions of the
>   nervous system.

**Humans**

> Oral exposure to aluminum is usually not harmful. Some studies
>   show that people exposed to high levels of aluminum may develop
>   Alzheimer’s disease, but other studies have not found this to be true.
>   We do not know for certain that aluminum causes Alzheimer’s disease.
>
> Some people who have kidney disease store a lot of aluminum in their
>   bodies. The kidney disease causes less aluminum to be removed from the
>   body in the urine. Sometimes, these people developed bone or brain
>   diseases that doctors think were caused by the excess aluminum.
>
> Although aluminum-containing over the counter oral products are
>   considered safe in healthy individuals at recommended doses, some
>   adverse effects have been observed following long-term use in some
>   individuals.

**Some regulation and recommendations:**

- **Drinking water**

> The EPA has recommended a Secondary Maximum Contaminant Level (SMCL)
>   of 0.05–0.2 mg/L for aluminum in drinking water. The SMCL is not based
>   on levels that will affect humans or animals. It is based on taste,
>   smell, or color.

- **Consumer products**

> The FDA has determined that aluminum used as food additives and
>   medicinals such as antacids are generally safe.
>
> FDA set a limit for bottled water of 0.2 mg/L.

- **Workplace air**

> OSHA set a legal limit of 15 mg/m3 (total dust) and 5 mg/m3
>   (respirable fraction) aluminum in dusts averaged over an 8 hour work
>   day.

Comment: Yep, good catch.  I needed to remove the Inhalation at the beginning of the sentence.  I'll revise to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: Why is there one section titled "Workers" and another "Humans"?

Comment: @Phil each of these species obviously lives in a different environment, thus have a different aluminium exposure ;)

Comment: @Phil: Possibly because some of it is taken from information provided for industrial safety uses?  After all, the only people who are likely to be exposed to large amounts of aluminum dust are people who work in aluminum-related industries.  Note also that inhaling large amounts of any sort of dust is not a good idea, and is rather different from ingesting material in solution.

Comment: @jamesqf are the workers not human then?

Comment: @Phil: When have I suggested otherwise?

Comment: @jamesqf by defending the incredibly odd scenario where we have information under two headings: "Workers" and "Humans".  It's clear from the content "Workers" does not refer to bees (for instance), but human beings who happen to be working with the stuff.  Which makes "Humans" an odd heading for the next paragraph.  It implies the other paragraph isn't referring to humans (ie, the workers aren't human).  Perhaps "Workers" and "The general public" would be a better set of headings?  Just defending it as copy-paste means the author was sloppy and lazy.

Comment: @Phil: As I said, because the only people likely to have significant long-term exposure to aluminum dust are those who work in aluminum-related industries.  Whereas "humans" - the general public PLUS workers - is about equally likely to be exposed to dissolved aluminum-containing chemicals from cooking pots, antacids, and the like.

Comment: Just as a note: _"some adverse effects [...] in some individuals"_ is extremely vague. It is unclear whether CDC refers to brain and bone disease observed in people with kidney disease, or to other adverse effects in otherwise healthy people.